# Find the optimal number of words in a string

Tags: php, wordpress

I've a project where product titles of different lengths are used. It can be either one word or ten. The issue is that only 2 lines for the title can be used in the design. Empirically, I found out that two fixed-width lines are about 90-100 characters long. So I need to truncate long strings, without break the words with dots interpolation. I'm used WordPress CMS for this project and WordPress has built-in function **[wp_trim_words()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_trim_words/)** which allows you to cut the string without break the words. But its disadvantage is that the words have different lengths and in some cases there is space for one or two more words.

So I wrote next code:

```php
$title = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In laborum quod aperiam veritatis dolore ipsa odit ducimus nulla!';

$length_of_title = strlen($title);

if ( $length_of_title >= 75 ) {
    $i = 1;
    $length = 0;
    while( $length <= 70 ) {
        $length = get_strlen_of_title($title, $i);  
        $i++;
    }
}

// this variable is used to output title
$title = wp_trim_words($title, $i, '...');

function get_strlen_of_title($title, $length) {
    $trim = wp_trim_words($title, $length);
    return strlen($trim);
}
```

Actually it works. But how could I improve it? I think the loop takes a lot of time to execute.

Comment: Why aren't you using CSS for this?

Comment: I don't think that the loop is so heavy, unless there are thousands of titles to trim.
Personally I will remove *function get_strlen_of_title* ans set ```$length =strlen(wp_trim_words($title, $i);``` (if that function is used only there)

Comment: $shortTitle = substr($title, 0, 75); $title = substr($shortTitle, 0, strrpos($shortTitle, ' '));